# How to know exactly the property that failed to convert its value when fetching data from Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can I know what exactly the property failed to convert a value when next database Exception happen? It's very difficult to catch property when you deal with the big node with nested other nodes!

> W/System.err: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException:
>    Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to double

The exception occurred in line 29

```
"delivery_fees": "9"
```

Next snippet database structure where the error occurs

```js
{
  ...
  "delivering_due_date": "09-08-2018 14:32:55",
  "delivery_day": "Tuesday",
  "delivery_end_time": "2018-05-29 14:12:11",
  "delivery_fees": "9",
  "delivery_payment_type": "Use Cash",
  "delivery_start_time": "2018-05-29 12:12:11",
  ...
}
```

Comment: Please add your database structure and indicate the line at which this error occurs.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thank you for your replay, I already able to find the failed property, but that take from me a lot of time of search with the general error message, so I wonder if there any way to directly selects the failed property.

Comment: That's why I have asked you to add the structure and to indicate the line at which this error occurs, so I can tell you the exact property.

Comment: @AlexMamo Could you check it now,  I'm updating the question and add database structure.

Comment: where is the code you are using to write to firebase database?

Comment: @UmarHussain I just fetch this value from Firebase database

Comment: you are reading the value from firebase or writing it to firebase ?

Comment: I'm reading this data from firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure that you have the required type for a field, set rules on firebase database to restrict a field to one type. In your case what happening is that you are expecting a integer/long value from database but its written as string to the database.

Trying to catch expection on client side is not ideal. The ideal solution is to restrict what data a field can accept.

Here is the intro to the rules: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

here is a simple tool by firebase team to write rules easily. https://github.com/firebase/bolt

It may look like a long solution but its the write way to free the client side from guessing what will be the type of the field.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I agree with you, but still, my question about is there any way to know what exactly property failed. not the just general exception message

Comment: It depends, your error is most probably when extracting value from snapshot and assigning to a variable, so the error is due to wrong data type and the error is wrapped in DatabaseException because the code is executed in the value event listener.

Comment: So you have to manually debug and find the error. Thats why I was suggesting to control it from rules.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the following line of code:

```
W/System.err: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to double
```

Because your `delivery_fees` property as I see in your database schema, is of type `String` and not of type `double`. So when you are trying to get its value as a `double`, you are getting this error saying that it cannot be converted, which is actually true because you cannot simply convert in Java a String object to a double.

There are two ways in which you can solve this. The first one would be to get the value of the `delivery_fees` property as String and then convert it to a double. The second one would be to change the type of the property to double, `"delivery_fees": "9"` -> `"delivery_fees": 9.01` and leave the getting method unchanged. The second approach is also what I also recomment it because the properties need to hold the values of the corresponding data type. This way you can benefit of the features that numbers provide.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but that not what I look for, I already know the exception location and fix it. What I look for is how to know that "delivery_fees" is failed parameter directly without the need to search on all node properties?

Comment: You don't have this details in your exception. With other words, the `DatabaseException` object doesn't cotains the actual name of the property at which it occurs, it just indicate the line in your code at which it occurs and then according to it, you can get the name from your database. Another approach would be to use security rules and restrict each property accordingly.

Comment: For writing security rules, the best solution in my opinion is to write the rules in a higher-level language, that compiles into Firebase Security rules. The most well-known ones are [Blaze](https://github.com/firebase/blaze_compiler) (the grand-daddy of them all), [Butane](https://github.com/aputinski/butane) (not from Firebase itself) and [Bolt](https://github.com/firebase/bolt) (new and under very active development). As far as I know, Bolt is a research only project and learning from the language was incorporated into firebase storage security rules and there is no official support for it.

Comment: @devqmr Hi devqmr! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: I'll work on add security role to firebase database, for my question I think the answer is NO as I see.